# Acer Travelmate does not boot (not even from CD)

Tags: boot, bios, acer-travelmate

I've got an old Acer Travelmate 7740ZG. Recently it broke somehow and now it refuses to boot. I know tons of users ask about booting problems again and again but there's something that seems really strange to me:

1. Trying to boot an OS results in a black screen with
   a flashing cursor
2. Pressing F2 during startup opens BIOS settings, it
   works perfectly
3. I am able to select the boot device (either by changing
   the boot preference or in the boot menu during startup), however the
   system never succeeds to boot. Here's a video: http://1drv.ms/1y46ySI

That means it's not an broken boot sector. Also it's not a motherboard or CPU failure as BIOS works fine (even with USB keyboard).

I've tried to boot the following:

- Windows 10 TP on HDD
- Windows 10 TP on a flash drive
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a flash drive
- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on a DVD

But all of them failed instantly (no loading etc.) and only a console-like screen (see #1) appeared.

Thanks for advice :)

Comment: Is there any RAM in it?

Comment: Yep. BIOS says `Total Memory: 4096 MB`

Comment: If the BIOS has some option ilke "Load safe defaults," have you tried that?

Comment: Sadly, that helps neither.

Comment: "console-like screen appeared" …Pictures might help, even just from a phone-cam posted to imgur, flickr etc & link added to your question.

Comment: @Tetsujin There's pretty much nothing to see. Just a black screen with a blinking white underscore cursor. http://1drv.ms/1NEJSdf

Comment: hmm… that's the 'found something, but can't figure out how to boot from it' sign. The "I'm still thinking but haven't yet made up my mind" logo. Drive is seen, boot is determined, but boot isn't happening. I'd suspect the drive/OS, except that you say it does it with *any* boot device. I'm stumped, sorry.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, that's the weird part. It does not accept CDs which it used to before.

Comment: Tried pulling the CMOS battery for 10 mins? [if it has one]

Comment: Still nothing... :(

Comment: As @ Tetsujin, the battery might be be an issue; it might need to be replaced (they also power the clock, so if time is *way* off in BIOS setup, that's an indication it's the battery).